# How to pull back data in SQL where a value from one column is matched in another column

Tags: python, sql-server, matching

SELECT @@Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
I'm looking to find in my data all examples of where a value in column B, such as "Apple" or "Cherry", is found in column C, and pull the original line of data for column B. Example data stack below.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |  |  |
| 2 | Orange | Apple | Return |
| 3 | Plum |  |  |
| 4 | Apple | Apple | Receive |
| 5 | Banana |  |  |
| 6 | Cherry |  |  |
| 7 | Peach |  |  |
| 8 | Peach | Cherry | Receive |
| 9 | Banana |  |  |
| 0 | Cherry | Cherry | Return |

Returned values expected:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |  |  |
| 2 | Orange | Apple | Return |
| 4 | Apple | Apple | Receive |
| 6 | Cherry |  |  |
| 8 | Peach | Cherry | Receive |
| 0 | Cherry | Cherry | Return |

I am fairly new to SQL and unsure if this is a lack of knowledge or a limitation of SQL data manipulation. I am also learning Python and if this needs to be manipulated in Python instead, I'll give it a shot.

Tried:

SELECT
*

WHERE

([Column B] is not null or [Column B] like [Column C])

FROM [DF]

Attempted code 2:

SELECT
concat([Column B],'-',[Column C])

FROM [DF]

where Column B like concat([Column B],'-',[Column C])

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ColumnA INT,  ColumnB VARCHAR(10), ColumnC VARCHAR(10), ColumnD VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @Table (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD) VALUES
(1, 'Apple  ', NULL, NULL), (2, 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Return'), (3, 'Plum', NULL, NULL), (4, 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Receive'),
(5, 'Banana', NULL, NULL), (6, 'Cherry', NULL, NULL), (7, 'Peach', NULL, NULL), (8, 'Peach', 'Cherry', 'Receive'),
(9, 'Banana', NULL, NULL), (0, 'Cherry', 'Cherry', 'Return');
```

It sounds like you're looking for a self-join, where you join a table back to itself:

```
SELECT *
  FROM @Table a
    INNER JOIN @Table b
      ON a.ColumnB = b.ColumnC;
```

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Apple | Apple | Receive | 2 | Orange | Apple | Return |
| 4 | Apple | Apple | Receive | 4 | Apple | Apple | Receive |
| 6 | Cherry |  |  | 8 | Peach | Cherry | Receive |
| 0 | Cherry | Cherry | Return | 8 | Peach | Cherry | Receive |
| 6 | Cherry |  |  | 0 | Cherry | Cherry | Return |
| 0 | Cherry | Cherry | Return | 0 | Cherry | Cherry | Return |

Comment: Thanks @Patrick! The self-join was the answer I was looking for. I ended up needing a right join to limit to exactly what I was looking for. Final code below in case anyone else runs into this:

Select 
*
From Table a
right Join Table b on a.ColumnB=b.ColumnC